# Is there a way to use Search Tweets: Full Archive / Sandbox with node.js?

Tags: node.js, twitter

I need to accumulate Tweets from a specific period of time based on a specific hashtag. Is there a library that supports the Search Tweets: Full Archive  /  Sandbox API? I tried Twit and twitter-node-client (which was suggested on the Twitter dev page) but didn't manage to go past the limit of one week old Tweets. Even though there is a limit of 100 tweets/request it should be able to get the Tweets from, for example, the 1st September 2019, or am i understanding something wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if those packages accommodate searching in those date ranges, but regardless it looks like you'd need Premium or higher API access to search outside 7 days:

[Search Tweets Feature summary](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/search/overview)

Comment: Thanks for your answer! According to https://developer.twitter.com/en/pricing/search-fullarchive there is a full history access in the sandbox package as well, but it still doesn't work...

Answer (score 0):

For everybody that comes across the same problem:

I managed to get the wanted Tweets by choosing Postman, it is probably the easiest way and gives the most readable results due to the JSON format. Most importantly: it didn't work with the usual four OAuth keys, instead it is needed to generate a Bearer Token to use the full archive sandbox endpoint.

I assume it would work with the twitter-node-client library as well because of the existing getCustomApiCall() method, but not sure how easily would the Bearer Token setup go.